# .htaccess remove query string, keeping SEO style url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

**Question:**

Is it possible to clear the `%{QUERY_STRING}` without breaking any functionality of what I've accomplished in my .htaccess file.

I want to prevent users from adding `?foo=bar` to the end of the url overwriting any predefined $_GET vars

**(external re_write) Example:**

From: `example.com/foo/bar/hello/world?test=blah`

To: `example.com/foo/bar/hello/world`

**So far I have been able to accomplish this (internally):**

From: `example.com/foo/bar/hello/world`

To: `example.com/index.php?foo=bar&hello=world`

**.htaccess**

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.(?:html?|php|aspx?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To externally redirect /dir/index to /dir/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s((.+)?(\/)?)?(index) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Prevent Rewrite on existing directories, files, and links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] #^ - [L]

# To internally rewrite directories as query string
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)=([^/]*)(/(.+))?\/?$ /$4?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)/([^/=]+)(/(.+))?\/?$ /$4?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)(/(.+))?\/?$ /$3?$1 [N,QSA]
```

**What I've tried:**

```
#if there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

-

```
#if there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

-

```
#if there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

I read somewhere, and experienced it, that applying the above breaks anything I've already accomplished. Completely clearing the whole url if they are masked $_GET vars. Even crashes apache 0.o (forgive me for any silly regex or .htaccess code, they're aren't my strong suite and most of it was snippets I found on SO)

is this possible? something I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[^\ ]+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

You need to match against the actual request because you're building a query string with these rules:

```
# To internally rewrite directories as query string
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)=([^/]*)(/(.+))?\/?$ /$4?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)/([^/=]+)(/(.+))?\/?$ /$4?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)(/(.+))?\/?$ /$3?$1 [N,QSA]
```

When these rules loop around, the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable will have stuff in it and your rules will clobber them. If you match against the actual request, your rewrites won't get affected.

Comment: same error I got with the others getting 403, It looks like it removes the query string. But url gets rewritten to `example.com/C:/PATH/TO/SITE/DIRECTORY/www/foo/bar` (on a windows box testing with xampp, target machine is a *nix box, not sure if that will affect it)

Comment: @StrikeForceZero Oh, so you either need a `RewriteBase /` or add a `/` in front of the `$1` in the rule's target.

Comment: thank you good sir, you are a genius! =) (I will be taking a peek at your android apps since I was browsing your site waiting for a response haha)