# apache url rewriting for random number

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

the thing is that im capturing my url based on GET method... so my url looks like

```
localhost/test/index.php?vic=24
```

where vic is variable...

ALSO i have a button on my site that is randomizing my vic every time.

```
<a href="'.htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?vic='.randomVic($link).'">
```

note that randomVic($link) is a function that returns random number every time.

what i want to achieve is that my url looks like

```
localhost/test/index.php?vic=24 -> localhost/test/24
```

and so on for every random number.
i really need help on this, i tried numerous .htacces mods for rewrite (striping .php, removing index, ...) but none of them worked as i needed them.

Thanks!

Comment: "i tried numerous .htacces mods for rewrite" - really? This is one of the simplest regexp rewrites, I saw. Show us your code, that doesn't work, please.

Comment: Rewrite rules become a lot clearer, in my opinion, if you stop thinking of them as making ugly URLs pretty, and start thinking of making pretty URLs ugly: your HTML should have the pretty version (`href="/test/'.randomVic($link).'"`) and your Apache rule then matches `/test/` followed by any number, and substitutes it onto the end of `/test/index.php?vic=` - which is indeed about as simple as rewrite rules get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess remove query string, keeping SEO style url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988685/htaccess-remove-query-string-keeping-seo-style-url)

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[^\ ]+
RewriteRule ^xampp/vic/([0-9]+)$ index.php?vic=$0

i get server error on xampp full path is: localhost/xampp/vic/index.php?vic=54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your **`DOCUMENT_ROOT/vic.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vic/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+vic/index\.php\?vic=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?vic=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: http://goo.gl/BqGdxh

click on a dice... nothing happens... i put your code in .htacces

Comment: Ah there was a typo. Fixed it, can you try now?

Comment: 404 error as you can see

Comment: What is the location of the above htaccess file? Also are there any other existing rules?

Comment: no, no other rewriting urls...  i put it in my root/vic dir

Comment: First of all you leave a comment and then disappear for many many hours :-) 2nd I clearly mentioned in my answer that this code goes in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file. If you want `DOCUMENT_ROOT/vic/.htaccess` then I can edit the answer.

Comment: Check the update for `DOCUMENT_ROOT/vic.htaccess` file.

Comment: well im sorry but im in croatia. when its day over there, its night here :( ill try this now... :)

EDIT: works as intended. Many thanks !

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)$ index.php?vic=$1
```

*edited as per comment below*

Comment: maybe the reason this doesnt work for me is because i use method GET to get vic every time.... should i switch to method POST with hidden input?

Comment: also if i put your rewrite rule i get server error on xampp
full path is: http://localhost/xampp/vic/index.php?vic=54


i changed test to vic/