# How to write an htaccess rule for this

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I am new to htaccess rules and i am finding it difficult to write a htaccess rules to convert

http://www.frontieragturf.com/category.php?cat_id=1   
to 
http://www.frontieragturf.com/category/1

I have tried these rules but that didn't work.

[.htaccess remove query string, keeping SEO style url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988685/htaccess-remove-query-string-keeping-seo-style-url)
[Customize Url or Hide Query String using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892542/customize-url-or-hide-query-string-using-htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "cat_id=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=302,L]
```

I have write this but its remove whole query string including 1 
like this http://www.frontieragturf.com/category.php

Comment: Please define "didn't work" and include code that you already have.

Comment: Rather than links you need to show your attempted code here.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/?$ category.php?cat_id=$1 [NC]`
And be sure mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: I have added my code. Please take a look

Comment: Do you want to convert a user query `http://www.frontieragturf.com/category.php?cat_id=1` to internally performing `http://www.frontieragturf.com/category/1` or vice versa? You question reads as if the former, but the latter would be more logical.

Comment: Please take a look at @DarkBee's answer.

Comment: @Debflav: I have tried DarkBee's answer but that didn't work.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh : I just want to convert it from http://www.frontieragturf.com/category.php?cat_id=1 to http://www.frontieragturf.com/category/1 not vice versa

Comment: @anubhava : Can you please suggest something ?

Comment: I have already posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^category\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /category/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Here, `%1` refers to the first matching group of the previous `RewriteCond`, while $1 would refer to the first matching group from this `RewriteRule`, like in `RewriteRule (.*) /category/$1`. The [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says:

> RewriteCond backreferences: These are backreferences of the form %N (0 <= N <= 9). %1 to %9 provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of conditions. %0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

The last `?` kills the original query string. Without it, it would be repeated for the redirected query: it would be `/category/1?cat_id=1`, while the OP needs `/category/1`.

Comment: An explanation enhances the quality of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?cat_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/?$ category.php?cat_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Change `302` to `301` once you verify it is working for you.

Comment: Anubhav your answer is working but now it adding category with every link for ex: earlier image url was like this http://www.frontieragturf.com/images/full/549631400862402.jpg  and now it is something like this http://www.frontieragturf.com/category/images/full/549631400862402.jpg any suggestion ?

Comment: Also this rule is only redirecting `/category.php?cat_id=123` so there is no way it can impact `/images`. You are most likely using relative paths for image/css/js. **Just use absolute paths** in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can also try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.